# How to display .msh file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I display My mesh file( contains a rows and columns of x y and z points) in Mat lab? I have tried using the surf option, but I am unable to do so.I want to display My mesh ( ie the shape of the mesh) in Surf plot

Comment: And we need a minimal example...

Comment: You may use [http://www.filedropper.com/](http://www.filedropper.com/) to share your .msh file, or simply paste some rows. How was it created?

Comment: The best is to edit your question and include your rows (comments skip the ends of line as you can see)

Comment: There might be a problem with your line breaks, if I put the data you pasted into a text file and load it with dlmread or importdata it works fine, IF I did the linebreaks manually...

Comment: i am sorry.. the data is in 3 columns and 50 rows, i can import this data.. problem is i do not know how to display it on surf. ie i want the plot.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, if your output is coming from a program like Gambit, I don't think you want to use `surf` at all.  (Spoiler: if you can export your mesh as an STL, just read the last line of this answer and click the link).

**First problem:** if you simply do `surf(M)` on data you have just loaded, Matlab will not (can not) determine that you intended these to be points in x, y, and z. From the docs:

> surf(Z)  creates a three-dimensional shaded surface from the z
>   components in matrix Z, using x = 1:n and y = 1:m, where [m,n] =
>   size(Z). The height, Z, is a single-valued function defined over a
>   geometrically rectangular grid. Z specifies the color data, as well as
>   surface height, so color is proportional to surface height.

**Next problem:** even if you extract X,Y, and Z points and call `surf(X,Y,Z)`, it is likely that you will get this error:

> Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

This is because `surf` expects Z to be an n x m matrix, where x and y are either vectors of sizes n and m respectively, or matrices with the same size as z.  i.e. x = 1:10, y=1:10, z is a 10 by 10 matrix is acceptable, or three 10 x 10 matrices.

**Last problem**: depends on the shape/nature of the surface you are trying to plot. There is no guarantee that your data will be plotted by `surf` in any way resembling the mesh you originally designed.  For example, just by listing the points at the corners of a simple cube and calling `surf`:

[image: the cube is a lie]

`surf` is really not designed for plotting arbitrary surfaces or complex meshes; it's for cases where `z = f(x,y);`.  The same goes for `mesh`. A better method is to define how your points are connected and use [patch](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/visualize/multifaceted-patches.html) (link to docs). The important line is basically:

`patch('Vertices',vertex_matrix,'Faces',faces_matrix)`

Where `vertex_matrix` would be your `M` and `faces_matrix` indicates which vertices are connected together.  There are various examples on the File Exchange of code written to import CAD meshes and convert into a suitable format for `patch`, for example [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22409-stl-file-reader) for STL files.

Answer (score 0):

Since I use `.msh` files for `CFD` I open them through the `QuickerSim CFD` module.

Code goes something like this:

```
[p,e,t] = importMeshGmsh('nameoffile.msh');
displayMesh2D(p,t);
```